# Problem with recognizing "\t" for vim in python output

Tags: python, vim, sed

I have a python code something like this

```
file_out.write(str(i).strip()+"\t"+str(dict1[i]).strip()+"\n")
```

But when i try to recognize this with vim by saying on the file that was written.

```
:%s/\t/|/g
```

But it does not recognize the `\t`

Comment: i don't have a problem with that. If you are searching for a literal \t, then in your Python script, you should escape your tab. ie `\\t`.

Comment: Sorry I had a \t and space after that in the file. So I wanted to replace all \t+space with just \t and Vi was nt able to find the \t+space pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
:%s/\\\t/|/g
```

because the `\` is itself a special char that needs escaping with `\`.

Comment: don't need to escape. if you escape it, you are actually searching for a literal \t.

Comment: He IS looking for a `\t` escape sequence appearing in his source code, so looking for literal `\t` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do `:%s/^V^I/|/g` where `^V` means control-V and `^I` means control-I -- that's how you get a tab into your vim command!

Comment: No need to type `<C-v>` unless `<Tab>` is mapped to something: substitute command does not have completion defined.